# Guava + merge multiple files and skip repeated headers

Tags: java, file, guava

I am trying to acheive the following.

Lets say we have two files - file1 and file 2 with the following contents

file1:

```
header
d1
d2
```

file2:

```
header
d3
d4
```

Then the merged file should be

Output file:

```
header
d1
d2
d3
d4
```

Note that we are skipping the header from the second file. I wrote the following code in Java using Guava.

```
    LinkedList<InputSupplier<BufferedReader>> listOfSuppliers = 
                new LinkedList<InputSupplier<BufferedReader>>();

        boolean firstFile = true;
        for (Path path : inputPaths) {

            InputSupplier<BufferedReader> reader = newBufferedReaderSupplier(fs.open(path));
            if (!firstFile) {
                String ignored = reader.getInput().readLine();
                LOGGER.info("Ignored header from the second file " + ignored);
            }
            listOfSuppliers.add(reader);
            firstFile = false;
        }

        InputSupplier<Reader> combined = CharStreams.join(listOfSuppliers);
        OutputSupplier<OutputStreamWriter> outputStream 
                = Files.newWriterSupplier(output, Charsets.UTF_8, false);
        CharStreams.copy(combined, outputStream);
```

The problem with this code is that when we skip the header, the output file has no contents from the second file. I think the BufferedReader is doing something which causes the entire file to be ignored.

Can idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm not sure about Guava classes, but `Files` from Java NIO has a `readAllLines` method that returns a `List<String>`. Use it on each of your files. Clear the first line of the second and append the two lists. Then write them to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid, it's all wrong. From the `InputSupplier.getInput()` javadoc:

> Like Iterable#iterator, this method may be called repeatedly to get independent channels to the same underlying resource.

This is the opposite of what you did in

```
String ignored = reader.getInput().readLine();
```

I guess, your InputSupplier doesn't obey the contract. If it did, the above line would be a no-op. Moreover, it would leave the stream open.<sup>1</sup>

You never said that your files are huge, so reading all of them via `Files.readLines`, manually removing the header line from all but the first, and concatenating is IMHO the way to go.

---

In case you find it inefficient, note that the most time-consuming part is probably the byte to char and back conversion. With UTF-8 (and many other encodings), skipping the first line can be done trivially with an `InputStream` (note that `BufferedReader` considers any of "\r", "\n", or "\r\n" to be a line break). But beware of the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)!

---

<sup>1</sup> While the suppliers were designed in order to prevent resource leaks, they have no magic achieving it. It's their use in the Byte/CharStreams methods which assures everything gets closed.